# findViewById throws a RuntimeException

Tags: android, view, runtimeexception

I modified my main.xml and my android app crashed.

I run debugger and find it threw a RuntimeException in

```
ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread$ActivityRecord, Intent) line: 2663
```

I can't understand where the bug is in my program. I bisected the code, and find this line threw it:

```
giveUpButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.GiveUpButton);
```

I'm sure because the exception disappeared after I removed this line.

I have no any idea. Why isn't the top of stack `findViewById`? Why does it throw exception?

I have this code in main.xml:

```
<Button
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="@string/give_up_button"
android:id="@+id/GiveUpButton"/>
```

Comment: If findViewById can't find the view, it will return null instead of throwing a runtimeexception. I'm very confused.

Comment: Yes, please show us the rest of the exception trace.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I know it sounds like a joke. But I have fixed the problem by... restarting my Eclipse.

It's very likely caused by Git's checkout. I switch between branches without closing Eclipse.

How can I avoid such a problem? It cost a lot of time to restart Eclipse over and over again.

Comment: I've seen something somewhat similar happening every now and then whilst using Eclipse. AFAIK the problem has occurred once I have saved a change in both code and layout xml file within one 'Save All'. This seems to confuse building in a way application never starts - but I've never done any digging on the root cause. Just saying this sounds similar. What I've done in these cases is selecting "Clean.." from Project menu.

Comment: Next time try a "Clean" of your project and see if that works before restarting.

Comment: thanks ! i've restart and it wad not enought, i did a Clean and now it's working ! i think you can validate your own anwser.

Answer (score 0):

did you

```
setContentView(R.layout.main)
```

before the line

```
giveUpButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.GiveUpButton);
```